# How do I change data displayed in a table cell to an alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone tell me the easiest way to change the grey cell into an alert box. I am trying to get a result to display as an alert box rather than in a read-only cell.
This is what I have so far...

```
<input readonly='readonly' type='text' tabindex='-1' style='overflow:hidden; border:0px   solid #000000; width:100%; padding-right:1px; background-color: #EEE;' name='XLEW_2_5_9' id='XLEW_2_5_9' class='ee128' />
```

What code should I put in the header and body?
Many thanks in advance
Nyree

Comment: Try yo explain what you want a bit better

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about two completely different html elements.

Comment: Well what I understand the result which is showing in this read Only field you want that result to show in an alert box.

If this is the case then I tink you need to modify that script which is returning the result insert alert there.

Comment: Hello, Sumair thanks for replying. I'm not allowed to post images which would have helped explain a bit better, but yes I want the read only field to display in an alert box, where do I find the script which is returning the result?, I'm new to javascript, sorry!

Comment: You shouldn't run alert in production code as it breaks the browser event loop

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you will need some javascript to get the value from the input field. Try this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var val = document.getElementById("XLEW_2_5_9").value;
    alert(val);
    </script>
```

Comment: Its in the right direction (I think) unfortunately I don't know enough about javascript to know what to take out or leave, here's the full code if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to show in a Javascript alert something you have now in a read-only cell...

instead of write the input code

```
<input readonly='readonly' type='text' tabindex='-1' style='overflow:hidden; border:0px   solid #000000; width:100%; padding-right:1px; background-color: #EEE;' name='XLEW_2_5_9' id='XLEW_2_5_9' class='ee128' />
```

you must write the alert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var alerttext=DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW;
    alert(alerttext);
</script>
```

when you give the value to the input (in your question, the `input` don't have `value` attribute)